# Could not load type when using servicestack and AppDynamics monitor

Tags: servicestack, appdynamics

When having the AppDynamics performance monitor installed, the servicestack API fails to load with the following exception:

Could not load type 'd__38' from assembly '###, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

StackTrace:
   at ###.BaseService`1.<Any>d__38.MoveNext() in ###\Services\BaseService.cs:line 190
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at ###.BaseService`1.Any(T request)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @mythz do you have any suggestion? The exception is thrown in ServiceRunner.Execute Thank you

Comment: also it's very hard to reproduce in local environment but it's reproducing all the time in production environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whom it might be of interest I have found a workaround and more details about this issue. This occurs only in the following scenario:

1. AppDynamics agent is installed and running
2. ServiceStack API is compiled using the MSBuild from c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe

If you use the MsBuild 14 that is installed along Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC then this issue does not occur anymore. From my first findings there is an issue in ServiceStack's way of caching the endpoints and wrapping the execute method using Linq but I don't understand why this happens only when AppDynamics agent is installed.

@mythz if you want to dig deeper into this issue I'm available to help but with the above solution everything is ok.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Love to help you out here, but there are no details about the error, please email help@appdynamics.com for assistance. I assume this is C#, but wouldn't know based on this. AppDynamics supports many languages and technologies.